# What is the best way to test if a Magnific Popup is currently "open"

Tags: magnific-popup

What is the best way to test if a Magnific Popup is currently "open"?

Will a check for the existence of some div be future proof?

For example, if I use:

```
if ($(".mfp-ready").length > 0)
  ...
```

I looked for the equivilent of an isopen property in the api documentation but found nothing like that

**EDIT**

Following Dmitry's answer, I examined the instance object and found the following properties that may prove useful to others:

```
isAndroid
isIE7
isIE8
isIOS
isLowIE
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$.magnificPopup.instance.isOpen`

Comment: So there is one.  Thank you.  Can you add the link to the relevant page where you found it in the magnific documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Here is simple solution from Magnific popup [documentation](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#options)

```
$('.image-link').on('mfpOpen', function(e /*, params */) {
  console.log('Popup opened',  $.magnificPopup.instance);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Old question, i know, but none of the other answers solved the same issue for me.

The next code solved it for me:

```
$('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
   callbacks: {
     open: function() {
       console.log('text to show in console if popup is open');
     }
   }
});
```